# Removing string and date from url with htaccess and rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to replace some parts of my url, year-month and also .html url extension.

Basically i want this ( old url )

```
https://olddomain.com/weblog/archives/2016/06/post-name-example.html
```

to redirected to

```
https://newdomain.com/post-name-example/
```

this url. I have searched stackoverflow and many other sites, tried mixing different answers from different people together. Tried writing my own rules but i couldn't pull it off. Any help would be much appreaciated. Thank you.

I tried this to remove .html extension

```
#1)redirect /file.html to /file

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
```

This to remove date format from url

```
# REMOVE DATE FROM WP POST PERMALINKS
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wordpress/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://example.com/$4

http://example.com/wordpress/2012/04/12/post-name/

..to elegance:

http://example.com/post-name/
```

My htaccess file is like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^weblog/archives/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)\.html$ https://newdomain.com/$1/ [R=301.L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This worked properly if anybody needs it in the future:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^weblog/archives/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I deleted the old rules but will try to bring together the solutions i tried. Will edit my question now.

Comment: Your `Redirect` looks ok and shoud work.  Does it redirect your old url to an unexpected location?

Comment: So what is the actual old URL format now? With the added example at the bottom, there’s two _different_ URL formats in this question now.

Comment: For what you _initially_ said you wanted to rewrite, `RewriteRule ^weblog/archives/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)\.html$ https://newdomain.com/$1/ [R=301.L]` should do the trick.

Comment: I just redirects everything to base of new url like newdomain.com @CBroe

Comment: No, that rule alone shouldn’t do that. Give us context, show us what else you have in your .htaccess. (And make sure you don’t get fooled by faulty previous attempts, that your browser might still have cached. For testing, always use status code 302 instead of 301, to avoid such problems.)

Comment: My entire htaccess file is. Sorry, can't format comment.  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^weblog/archives/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)\.html$ https://newdomain.com/$1/ [R=301.L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @ErdemÇelik You need to _edit_ your question to include the contents of your `.htaccess` file. _Unformatted_ code can result in special characters being omitted, rendering the code seemingly invalid (not simply hard to read).

Comment: Presumably "old domain" and "new domain" are both pointing to the same account/site?

Comment: No they are different domains on same server.

Comment: I have managed to make it work, now i need to cover every other url and redirect them to just homepage or new url. How should i do that without breaking or overlapping this rule? @AmitVerma